# How to avoid storing objects while performing large matrix and vector operations in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, lapply

As given in the code below, we are performing matrix operations over three variables V1, V2 , and V3 in dataframe DF5. While the end result we need is matV1, matV2, and matV3 for V1, V2 , and V3, respectively, we are storing a lot of objects while using the code. This process takes a lot of time when DF5 consists of a million row of data. How can we perform the following operation while storing least number of objects?

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
# STEP 1
#V1
setDT(DF5)
numvec <- max(DF5[,k])
dlV1 <- lapply(1:numvec, function(i) DF5[k == i, sort(V1)])
dmatV1 <- CJ(x=1:numvec, y=1:numvec)[, .(z = sum(findInterval(dlV1[[y]],dlV1[[x]]))), .(x,y)]
matV1 <- as.matrix(dcast(dmatV1, x~y, value.var = 'z')[, -'x'])
diag(matV1) <- 0
#V2
dlV2 <- lapply(1:numvec, function(i) DF5[k == i, sort(V2)])
dmatV2 <- CJ(x=1:numvec, y=1:numvec)[, .(z = sum(findInterval(dlV2[[y]],dlV2[[x]]))), .(x,y)]
matV2 <- as.matrix(dcast(dmatV2, x~y, value.var = 'z')[, -'x'])
diag(matV2) <- 0
#V3
dlV3 <- lapply(1:numvec, function(i) DF5[k == i, sort(V3)])
dmatV3 <- CJ(x=1:numvec, y=1:numvec)[, .(z = sum(findInterval(dlV3[[y]],dlV3[[x]]))), .(x,y)]
matV3 <- as.matrix(dcast(dmatV3, x~y, value.var = 'z')[, -'x'])
diag(matV3) <- 0

#STEP 2: Divide
matV12<-sweep(matV1, 2, 10, FUN = '/')
matV22<-sweep(matV2, 2, 10, FUN = '/')
matV32<-sweep(matV3, 2, 10, FUN = '/')

Lists <- list(matV12, matV22, matV32)
E<-Reduce("*", Lists)
    
#STEP 3
RESULT<-data.frame(rowSums(E))
```

Comment: What is `k` in the example.  Is this from another loop

Comment: k here is the iterator for column

Comment: You may simplify this to one -level of simplicity by converting the monolith to more modular with a wrapper function for the repeating cases